# Hadoop: Control Characters in output inspiring compression

Tags: hadoop

It's Friday, I'm super tired, and I was up against a really strange issue.

In my Reducer, I have a Text output. It contains a string with a custom delimiter, to be split on the next MapReduce job.

Thinking I was clever, the delimiter I used was a control character, U+0002.

When it was output, the file was compressed. It was not compressed before I was splitting anything. I very specifically need to avoid compression for my own reasons. I tried turning compression off manually, but to no avail. I was very frustrated for about an hour or two trying everything I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is... don't use control characters in your output. Or at least that's the answer as far as I can tell! I'd be curious to hear if anyone else have come up against the same issue.